# Having trouble with recursive function in c

Tags: recursion, cs50

I was just tryigng the exercise mentioned in the short on recursive functions. I have written this code but when i run it (even using debug 50) it just seems to brcome non responsive after the scanf statement on line 10.

anyone have any ideas where I have gone worng?

Thanks in advance

Alex

```
'''
#include <stdio.h>

int collatz;
int Collatz (int n);

int main (void)
{

    printf("Int:");
    int n = scanf("%d \n", &n);
    Collatz(n);
    //printf("Collatz: %i\n", collatz);
}


int Collatz(n)
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
         printf("Collatz: %i\n", collatz);
        return collatz;
    }

    else if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        collatz++;
        n = n/2;
        Collatz(n);

    }

    else
    {
        collatz++;
        n = 3 * n+1;
        Collatz(n);
    }


    return 1;
}

'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new to Stack Overflow so my answer maybe not ideal but at least will help you I hope.
So, one obvious thing is that you assign the returned value from scanf to variable n which is not supposed to be correct(as much as I understand the task) because n will be always 1 as scanf returns the number of successful inputs scanned and assigned. Also, you need to remove the new line in scanf so that after return(enter) it will read and assign input to variable n.
I also wonder whether it compiles as in function Collatz passed argument's type is not defined to be int. I changed the code a bit and it works properly I think.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int collatz;

int Collatz(int n);

int main(void) {

    printf("Int:");
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    Collatz(n);
    //printf("Collatz: %i\n", collatz);
}


int Collatz(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        printf("Collatz: %i\n", collatz);
        return collatz;
    } else if (n % 2 == 0) {
        collatz++;
        n = n / 2;
        Collatz(n);

    } else {
        collatz++;
        n = 3 * n + 1;
        Collatz(n);
    }


    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that fixed it thanks!   I understand the part about asigning the int to scanf but im alittle confused as to why the \n broke it.  It would compile and just get stuck. Ill put it down as a lesson learnt.  Thnaks for your help